# Postgres приведение bit(n) к bytea

Tags: postgresql

Не удается изменить тип колонки в PostgreSQL:

```
ALTER TABLE t_handbook
       ALTER COLUMN mask TYPE BYTEA USING (mask::BYTEA);
```

> ERROR:  cannot cast type bit to bytea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В списке рассылки pgsql-patches [обсуждалось](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/5171.1146927915@sss.pgh.pa.us#5171.1146927915@sss.pgh.pa.us) предложение добавить преобразование `bit(n)` ↔ `bytea`.

Но, судя по всему, патч был отклонен.

> I am not sure this is of general enough usefulness to be in the backend.
>
> It's not immediately
>   obvious that there should be a cast between bit(n) and bytea.

Перевод:

> Я не уверен, что целесообразно включать этот функционал в бэкэнд.
>
> Не совсем очевидно, что должно существовать приведение между типами bit(n) и bytea.

Проблема тут в семантике этих типов.

### bit(n)

`bit(n)` - это битовая строка фиксированной длины (и совсем не обязательно кратной 8), которая c одной стороны ведет себя как строка:

- при увеличении размерности добивается нулями справа;

  ```
  select B'10'::bit(4)

  1000
  ```
- при уменьшении размерности лишние разряды отсекаются справа (**младшие**);

  ```
  select B'1000'::bit(2)

  10
  ```
- две строки можно конкатенировать;

  ```
  select B'1000'::bit(4)||B'1001'::bit(4)

  10001001
  ```
- применять другие строковые операции (взятие подстроки, нахождение длины и т.п.).

С другой - этот тип похож на целое число с произвольным количеством двоичных разрядов.

- над битовой строкой можно выполнять операции битовой арифметики (`И` - `&`, `ИЛИ` - `|`, `ИСКЛЮЧАЮЩЕЕ ИЛИ` - `#`, `НЕ` - `~`, сдвиги `<<` и `>>`), устанавливать и сбрасывать отдельные биты;
- битовую строку можно приводить к целочисленным типам, при этом нулями будут заполнены недостающие **старшие** разряды;

  ```
  select B'1000'::int

  8
  ```
- целочисленные типы можно приводить к битовой строке, при этом, если строка меньше исходного типа - будет отброшены **старшие** разряды;

  ```
  select B'1000'::int::bit(1)

  0
  ```

### bytea

`bytea` - это по сути массив байтов (октетов) произвольной длины. Он похож на строку, но не имеет ограничений на значение каждого элемента.

### Почему же нельзя автоматически взять и положить `bit(n)` в `bytea` и наоборот?

Есть два момента:

1. **Кратность 8 битам.** Если длина битовой строки не кратна восьми неочевидно как добивать ее до нужной кратности при помещении в `bytea`. С начала или с конца, все в месте или побайтово? В самом деле `B'11111111'||B'1'` должно превратиться в `E'\\xFF80'`, `E'\\x01FF'` или вообще `E'\\xFF01'`?

   И как отрезать лишнее при обратном приведении? Возьмем значение `bytea`, например, `E'\\xFF0001'` (11111111 00000000 00000001) и приведем его к `bit(9)`. Есть варианты:

   - брать биты просто подряд от старшего к младшему побайтово

     [**11111111 0**0000000 00000001]

     `E'\\xFF0001'::bit(9)` → `B'1111111110'`
   - брать ближайшее в большую сторону кратное восьми количество бит и отбрасывать старшие биты

     [1111111**1 00000000**] 00000001

     `E'\\xFF0001'::bit(9)` → `B'100000000'`
   - выравниваться на младший бит младшего байта

     [11111111 0000000**0 00000001**]

     `E'\\xFF0001'::bit(9)` → `B'000000001'`
2. **Порядок байт**. Существуют разные порядки байт. Нужно ли предпочесть какой-то один порядок байт? Что делать, если на клиенте и сервере аппаратные платформы используют разный порядок байт (а приведение типов производится на сервере и на уровне операций с памятью).

   Из-за этих неопределенностей PostgreSQL не позволяет приводить, например, `int` к `bytea`. В случае с типом `bit(n)` все усугубляется необходимостью паддинга до целых байт (см. выше).

   Поэтому преобразование числовых типов к `bytea` личное дело каждого.

Comment: прям прочитал и почувствовал как умнею. приятное чувство

Comment: все таки не баг, а фича

Answer (score 2):

1. Создайте новую колонку с новым типом
2. Скопируйте данные через Update
3. Удалите старую колонку
4. Если нужно переименуйте название колонки

Comment: так это ж не правильный подход. это что баг? вот из text в int можно переименовать. а эти типы чем плохи?

Comment: @des1roer, что неправильного в аккуратной миграции с изменением типа данных?

Comment: @des1roer не для всех типов можно легко мигрировать данные, к примеру из строки в числа. Из за этого я всегда пользуюсь этим алгоритмом.

Comment: да хотя бы тем что один sql запрос лучше 4 действий

Comment: @des1roer не всегда это работает. А так выбор за вами. Никто не заставляет

Comment: Разработчики [отклонили патч](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200605060233.k462Xac03591@candle.pha.pa.us), добавляющий такое преобразование, мотивировав это тем, что он рассчитывает на определённые сходства во внутреннем представлении.